# accessing Request parameter in registerController validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

i have 2 type of user with different fields/columns in db (not the users table , users table is the same for both they have different profiles )

so in my registerController.php i have this validation function

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

which only covers 1 type of user , i need to access to

```
$request->input('user_type');
```

in this function so i can run proper validation for each users

i've tried something that used to work in older laravel version

```
private $request ; 
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
    $this->request = $request ; 
}
```

but in the 5.5 version of laravel it doesn't work i get

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when Laravel cannot resolve a dependency to the your `__construct` method. In your case this is `Request $request`. As shown in your error it is trying to inject a dependency `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` that cannot be resolved by laravel (do not have the answer to that).

Probably a quick fix for you would be to import the correct dependency at the start of your file.

```
<?php

namespace ...;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzleRequest;
```

Comment: thanx turns out i needed to import  `Illuminate\Http\Request` but my editor(phpstorm) was importing  `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request`